# Change Line Height of Google Doc through Google Drive API

Tags: api, google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

I cannot figure out how to change the document formatting options through the Google Drive API.  Is this not supported?  As of now I am uploading a file but Google is making the line height 1.15, but I want it to be Single (or 1).

Comment: wrong api. The drive api knows nothing about the contents of files

Comment: You may think to use https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#what_can_this_api_do but it says it's deprecated to Google Drive API.  Then which should I use?

Comment: docslist was also the wrong API. Drive is simply docslist v4. The only API I know of that will allow you to manipulate a document's contents is the one for Apps Script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Drive doesn't provide fine-grained controls to alter Google Docs, Sheets, etc. You can import files in other formats and convert them to Google formats, but you can't manipulate individual properties of the resulting files, including line height.